# Transfer files from a second remote (Ubuntu) to my local (Windoes 10)

Tags: scp, putty

I use `ssh` in a `PuTTY` terminal in my laptop (Windows 10) to connect to the campus Ubuntu server and then use `ssh` once more to connect to my office computer (Ubuntu).

I use the `PuTTY` terminal on my laptop and run the following command to copy a folder from the office computer (Ubuntu) to my laptop (Windows 10) but it says

> Could not resolve hostname c: Temporary failure in name resolution

```
scp -r username@PCname:/path/to/source/Folder "C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\new_folder"
```

I also tried:

```
scp -r username@PCname:/path/to/source/Folder MyName@DESKTOP-DeviceName:\Users\Mike\Desktop\new_folder
```

Other options that I tried but didn't work:

```
pscp -r username@PCname:/path/to/source/Folder C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\new_folder

pscp -r username@PCname:/path/to/source/Folder \Users\Mike\Desktop\new_folder
```

The last script is showing that it is copying the files. But, when I check the folder, I see that the files have not been copied.

By the way, I used `WinSCP` too. But it connects me to the campus server, not my office PC. So, I couldn't find the folder to copy it in the graphical interface.

Any comment is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use local commandline OpenSSH `scp`/`sftp` with `-J` (jump switch).

```
scp -r -J username@intermediate.example.com username@final.example.com:/remote/path C:\local\path
```

---

You can also use (my) WinSCP GUI, as it supports tunneling:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_tunnel